# Javascript Duplicates Function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

i have the following code which i found in fiddle as an example http://jsfiddle.net/x4E5Q/1/. I would like to have two identical select inputs and when I choose on value from the first one the same value on the second one NOT to be selectable.I put all in a single file but it doesn't work as it is meant to be.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function preventDupes( select, index ) {
    var options = select.options,
        len = options.length;
    while( len-- ) {
        options[ len ].disabled = false;
    }
    select.options[ index ].disabled = true;
    if( index === select.selectedIndex ) {
        alert('You\'ve already selected the item "' + select.options[index].text + '".\n\nPlease choose another.');
        this.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
}

var select1 = select = document.getElementById( 'select1' );
var select2 = select = document.getElementById( 'select2' );

select1.onchange = function() {
    preventDupes.call(this, select2, this.selectedIndex );
};

select2.onchange = function() {
    preventDupes.call(this, select1, this.selectedIndex );
};

</script>

<select id="select1" name="indication_subject[]">
  <option value="" selected="selected">a </option>
  <option> Accounting</option>
  <option> Afrikaans</option>
  <option> Applied Information and Communication Technology</option>
  <option> Arabic</option>
  <option> Art and Design</option>
  <option> Biology</option>
  <option> Business Studies</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" name="indication_subject[]">
  <option value="" selected="selected">a </option>
  <option> Accounting</option>
  <option> Afrikaans</option>
  <option> Applied Information and Communication Technology</option>
  <option> Arabic</option>
  <option> Art and Design</option>
  <option> Biology</option>
  <option> Business Studies</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly ?

Comment: Without the window.addEventListener("load",function(){....{} it doesn't work...i fixed it up and everything is ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need trigger your code after the page is loaded, like bellow

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", function(){

  function preventDupes( select, index ) {
      var options = select.options,
         len = options.length;
      while( len-- ) {
          options[ len ].disabled = false;
      }
      select.options[ index ].disabled = true;
      if( index === select.selectedIndex ) {
          alert('You\'ve already selected the item "' + select.options[index].text + '".\n\nPlease choose another.');
          this.selectedIndex = 0;
      }
  }

  var select1 = select = document.getElementById( 'select1' );
  var select2 = select = document.getElementById( 'select2' );

  select1.onchange = function() {
      preventDupes.call(this, select2, this.selectedIndex );
  };

  select2.onchange = function() {
      preventDupes.call(this, select1, this.selectedIndex );
  };
});
</script>

<select id="select1" name="indication_subject[]">
  <option value="" selected="selected">a </option>
  <option> Accounting</option>
  <option> Afrikaans</option>
  <option> Applied Information and Communication Technology</option>
  <option> Arabic</option>
  <option> Art and Design</option>
  <option> Biology</option>
  <option> Business Studies</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" name="indication_subject[]">
  <option value="" selected="selected">a </option>
  <option> Accounting</option>
  <option> Afrikaans</option>
  <option> Applied Information and Communication Technology</option>
  <option> Arabic</option>
  <option> Art and Design</option>
  <option> Biology</option>
  <option> Business Studies</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

or put the script after you code in DOM...

```
<body>
 <!-- your html -->
 <script>
  //your code
  </script>
</body>
```

the 2 ways work

Answer (score 1):

You should run the js on window.load (or document ready). Just wrap the entire js in a function like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
//your code
}
```

The fiddle works because it is set to run the js onLoad by default. If you set it to head--no wrap it will no longer work.